# QCombobox of Checkboxes

Tags: qt, qcombobox, qcheckbox

I have a problem and I hope that you can help me. I want to create a Combobox of Checkboxes on Qt Creator. This is my code

```
mod = new QStandardItemModel(1,0);
QStandardItem *item;
item = new QStandardItem("First");
item->setCheckable(true);
mod->setItem(0,item);
item = new QStandardItem("Second");
item->setCheckable(true);
mod->setItem(1,item);
ui->comboBox->setModel(mod);
```

I built this code but in combobox are no checkboxees. Someone on the web told me that I have to use the event. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

you only have to set an initial checkState additonally

```
item->setCheckState(Qt::CheckState state);
```

e.g.

```
item->setCheckState(0);
```