# How to make items in QComboBox class checkable PYQT5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qcombobox

I am trying to make my QComboBox checkable. I searched for similar posts but many of them remain unanswered and I did not manage to apply solution posted here ([QCombobox of Checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29589274/qcombobox-of-checkboxes)). At the moment I have this class defined:

```
class myCombo(QComboBox):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(myCombo, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setStyleSheet("QComboBox{"
                           "font-size:12px;"
                           "color:black;"
                           "background-color:white;"
                           "border:1px solid black;"
                           "padding:1px;""}")

        self.setEditable(True)
        self.lineEdit().setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.lineEdit().setReadOnly(True)
```

My Goal is to add a property that enables checking the items so that multiple choices can be made. Can this be managed without hardcoding this 'checkbox' into QComboBox?

The QComboBox class defined above is utilized like this:

```
class sWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        years = [' ', '2017', '2018', '2019', '2020']
        months = [' ', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12']

        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(360, 140))    
        self.setWindowTitle("Dialog") 

        self.yearLabel = QLabel(self)
        self.yearLabel.setText('Select Year(s):')
        self.firstLine = myCombo(self)
        self.firstLine.addItems(years)
        self.firstLine.move(120, 20)
        self.firstLine.resize(200, 32)
        self.yearLabel.move(20, 20)

        self.monthLabel = QLabel(self)
        self.monthLabel.setText('Select Month(s):')
        self.secondLine = myCombo(self)
        self.secondLine.addItems(months)
        self.secondLine.move(120, 60)
        self.secondLine.resize(200, 32)
        self.monthLabel.move(20, 60)

        okButton = QPushButton('OK', self)
        okButton.clicked.connect(self.okClicked)
        okButton.resize(100, 32)
        okButton.move(120, 100)

        cancelB = QPushButton('Cancel', self)
        cancelB.clicked.connect(self.cancelClicked)
        cancelB.resize(100, 32)
        cancelB.move(220, 100)  

    def okClicked(self):
        self.close()

    def cancelClicked(self):
        self.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = sWindow()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I would like it to be possible to select 1,2,3 in month combobox for example. Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: This isn't a duplicate question -- the answer in the linked question only works in PyQt4, and this question explicitly asks about PyQt5

Answer (score 0):

With this useful link:

[PyQt: How to set Combobox Items be Checkable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22775095/pyqt-how-to-set-combobox-items-be-checkable)

I managed to make it work (example with one combobox containing checkable years):

```
class CheckableComboBox(QComboBox):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(CheckableComboBox, self).__init__(parent)
        self.view().pressed.connect(self.handleItemPressed)
        self.setModel(QStandardItemModel(self))

    def handleItemPressed(self, index):
        item = self.model().itemFromIndex(index)
        if item.checkState() == Qt.Checked:
            item.setCheckState(Qt.Unchecked)
        else:
            item.setCheckState(Qt.Checked)

class Dialog_01(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(QMainWindow,self).__init__()

        years = ['2017', '2018', '2019', '2020']

        myQWidget = QWidget()
        myBoxLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        myQWidget.setLayout(myBoxLayout)
        self.setCentralWidget(myQWidget)
        self.ComboBox = CheckableComboBox()
        for index, element in enumerate(years):
            self.ComboBox.addItem(element)
            item = self.ComboBox.model().item(index, 0)
            item.setCheckState(Qt.Unchecked)
        myBoxLayout.addWidget(self.ComboBox)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Dialog_01()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```